# how do I prevent php (int) from converting null to 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using JQuery Ajax to send POST variables to php, some of these variables are not defined yet so I declare them and give them `null` like this:

```
if ($(this).is('.filters')) {
    alert("works");
}
else {
    var type = status = bhk = null;
}
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/search',
    data: {
        'do': getUrlParameter('do'),
        'use': use,
        'type': type, //null for now
        'status': status, //null for now
        'bhk': bhk, //null for now
        'city': $('select[name="city"]').val(),
        'zone': $('select[name="zone"]').val(),
        'page': page
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    if ($('#search').is(':visible'))
        $('#search').hide();

    var new_content = $(data).find('#search-filters, #scroll-to-list');
    $( '#results' ).html( new_content );

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#scroll-to-list').offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

In the php page I declare and filter them:

```
$use            = isset( $_POST['use'] ) ? (int) $_POST['use'] : '';        // int AJAX
$filter_type    = isset( $_POST['type'] ) ? (int) $_POST['type'] : '';      // int AJAX
$filter_status  = isset( $_POST['status'] ) ? (int) $_POST['status'] : '';  // int AJAX
$filter_bhk     = isset( $_POST['bhk'] ) ? (int) $_POST['bhk'] : '';        // int AJAX
$filter_city    = isset( $_POST['city'] ) ? (int) $_POST['city'] : 0;         // int AJAX
$filter_zone    = isset( $_POST['zone'] ) ? (int) $_POST['zone'] : 0;         // int AJAX
$page_number    = isset( $_POST['page'] ) ? (int) $_POST['page'] : '';      // int AJAX
```

I'm using those variables to create additional conditions for the MySQLi Select but if instead of null they are 0 I get an error:

```
if ($filter_type != NULL || $filter_type != '') {
    $filter_type = 'AND t2.type = ' . $filter_type;
} else $filter_type = NULL;
if ($filter_status != NULL || $filter_status != '') {
    $filter_status = 'AND t2.status = ' . $filter_status;
} else $filter_status = NULL;
if ($filter_bhk != NULL || $filter_bhk != '') {
    $filter_bhk  = 'AND t2.bhk = ' . $filter_bhk;
} else $filter_bhk = NULL;

if ($filter_city != 0) {
    $filter_city = 'AND t2.city = ' . $filter_city;
    $filter_zone = NULL;

    if ($filter_zone != 0) {
        $filter_zone = 'AND t2.zone = ' . $filter_zone;
    }
} else $filter_city = $filter_zone = NULL;

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(' SELECT t1.id, t2.*
                               FROM ' . $table . ' t1
                               INNER JOIN property t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
                               WHERE t2.use = ?
                               ' . $filter_type
                                 . $filter_status
                                 . $filter_bhk
                                 . $filter_city
                                 . $filter_zone . '
                               LIMIT ?, ?')) {
```

Aside from that, is there a cleaner or optimized way of doing this? I'd appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Change your `NULL` to `""`

Comment: from the jquery right?

Comment: And also in the ifs `$filter_type != ''`?

Comment: It's okay just add `|| $filter_type != ""`

Comment: I'm getting mysql error near `'000 LIMIT ?, ?' at line 5`

Comment: Add that code in all your if`s

Comment: Ok it's fixed. Thanks!